# Como mudar um DatetimeIndex para exibir meses em português usando a função month_name

Tags: python, windows, pandas

Gostaria de saber como mudar a localização de um DatetimeIndex do pandas para exibir os meses em outra língua, sem ser o inglês que é o padrão do pandas. Tentei usar "locale" no argumento da função *month_name* do DatetimeIndex, porém sem sucesso.

```
filename = "files/speed_check.csv"
speed_check = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";", infer_datetime_format=True, index_col="Date", parse_dates=True)
mensal = speed_check.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).mean()
mensal.index = mensal.index.month_name()
mensal
```

[image: A dúvida]

Quando insero "locale='French'" por exemplo, no argumento de month_name resulta em erro de locale inválido. Tentei também mudar a localização por meio de um

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'French')
```

porém, sem sucesso novamente.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nisso aqui, acho que pode te ajudar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55532672/python-how-to-set-french-locale

Comment: Uso Windows 10 e consigo mudar as configurações de localização do python pela lib locale, porém com o Pandas simplesmente não funciona. Ao executar `mensal.index.month_name(locale='French')`  resulta num erro _unsupported locale setting_

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR `idx.month_name(locale="pt_BR.utf-8")`

Veja exemplo:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> idx = pd.date_range(start='2018-01', freq='M', periods=3)

>>> idx
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')

>>> idx.month_name()
Index(['January', 'February', 'March'], dtype='object')

>>> idx.month_name(locale="pt_BR.utf-8")
Index(['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março'], dtype='object')
```